# bash script wget download files by date

Tags: bash, http, wget

I'm new to the world of bash scripting. Hoping to seek some help here.
Been messing about with the 'wget' command and found that it is quite neat! At the moment, it gets all contents from a https site, including all directories, and saves them all accordingly. Here's the command:

```
wget -r -nH –cut-dirs=1 -R index.html -P /home/snoiniM/data/in/ https://www.someWebSite.com/folder/level2 --user=someUserName --password=P@ssword
```

> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level2/level2-2013-07-01.zip saved
> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level2/level2-2013-07-02.zip saved 
> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level2/level2-2013-07-03.zip saved 
>
> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level3/level3-2013-07-01.zip saved 
> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level3/level3-2013-07-02.zip saved 
> /home/snoiniM/data/in/folder/level3/level3-2013-07-03.zip saved

That is fine for all intends and purposes. But what if I really just want to get a specific date from all its directories? E.g. just level*x*-2013-07-03.zip from all dirs within folder and save all to 1 directory locally (e.g. all *zip will be in ...folder/)

Does anyone know how to do this?

I found that dropping -cut-dirs=1 and on the URL www.someWebsite.com/folder/ is sufficient.

Also, with that in mind, added the -nd option. This means no directories -- "Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively. With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering."

This means, we're left with one more part -- how to write a bash script, which gets yesterday date, parse it to the wget command as a parameter?

E.g.
wget -r -nH -nd -R index.html -A ***$yesterday**.zip -P /home/snoiniM/data/in/ https://www.someWebSite.com/folder/ --user=someUserName --password=P@ssword

Comment: The current wget command does the following:
Get files recursively in the directory 1 level above.
-R is get all files except index.html.
Save files to /home/snoiniM/data/in/.

Answer (score 0):

Just the snippet you are looking for:

yesterday=$(date --date="@$(($(date +%s)-86400))" +%Y-%m-%d)

And no need of the * before yesterday; just treat it as a suffix.

Comment: Cool! thanks! In your expression above, where does it say "1 day" like we can with the -d option? It's not clear how to get 2 days ago, or 1 month ago.

I know I can use the following: date +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 day"

Comment: One day is 86400 seconds. I use the %s format of date, or "seconds since the epoch".